# DACPAC Deployments and RM - how to tokenize DACPAC scripts?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, ms-release-management, dacpac

I have a DACPAC deployment with some scripts that get "baked in" to the `database.dacpac` file prior to publish.  I need to tokenize some of these scripts - which poses a challenge because the DACPAC is compiled before it hits RM.

Is there any way I can have the SQL script reference an external file that is tokenizable - this way when RM actually publishes, the DACPAC references this file?

For example - somehow getting the following into an externally referenced sql file that is NOT baked into the dacpac and sits on disk alongside it:

```
INSERT INTO @table (Param1,Param2)
VALUES (__Value1__, __Value2__)
```

**Edit**

Based on the comments, I'm thinking it may be possible to pass the values into SQLPackage.  Does anyone know how I can leverage publish profiles to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it data in a table or different tables, procedures etc?

Comment: Did you try to use the SqlCMD variables?

Comment: @EdElliott I want to specify the data in Release Management tokenization - like this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/10/15/tokenization-with-release-management/

Comment: @ds19 hmm... I'm missing something.  How does this help me use RM?  Are you saying - pass the "values" into SQLCMD when publishing the dacpac?  My only issue there is the maintainability - I'd like to tokenize vs parameterize

Comment: I would do what @ds19 suggests - you will need to pass your token into sqlpackage (or however you deploy) as a sqlcmd variable and in your deployment script either use the token in the data or use the token to hit if statement blocks with your data in. There are other approaches but they are variations on the same theme.

Comment: @EdElliott - any idea how I can use a publish profile to store these key/value pairs?

Comment: @ds19 - I'm playing with the idea of using publish profiles for this - any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: @RobVious on my work we're doing in this way: the publish profiles are stored in .sqlproj projects so the developers can adjust them accordingly  (use different values for sqlcmd variables in different environments) and we have a publish profile for each environment; the PowerShell script that is deploying the .dacpac "knows" which profile to use based on the environment name; or 
you can use the newly updated build task [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) that supports .dacpac deployment.